# Rails 6: CSV is returned at the response payload but not downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a view that allows a user to select a group of records to be exported in a CSV file.

After the user selects a set of records and submits the form with the information, the CSV is correctly generated and returned but, instead of asking the user where to save the file, nothing happens. After inspecting the request at the browser, I discovered that the data is present at the response payload, as a raw CSV. How can I make the browser show the save dialog instead?

---

The view has a form containing the list of records and each record can be selected (with a checkbox) to be exported.

```rb
<%= form_with url: export_to_csv_admin_properties_url, multipart: true do |form| %>
  <table class="table is-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th><%= sortable "id" %></th>
          <th><%= sortable "city" %></th>
          <th>To export</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @properties.each do |property| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= property.id %></td>
        <td> <%= property.city %> </td>
        <td><%= check_box("export", property.id) %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <%= form.submit "Export" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller receives the data correctly and invokes the class responsible for building the CSV string:

```rb
def export_to_csv
  ids_to_export = params[:export].select { |_key, value| value == '1' }.keys
  properties = Property.find(ids_to_export)
  csv_data = CsvService.export_properties(properties)

  send_data csv_data, filename: "exported_properties.csv", type: 'text/csv'
end
```

Comment: @dbugger, `csv_data` is a String, doesn't have a `#read` method. What is the second parameter, `a`?

Comment: If you're using `send_data` to return a file you want to be downloaded by the browser, you'll probably want to add `disposition: 'attachment; filename=exported_properties.csv'` or similar, according to the docs. Also, you should be doing your `send_data` in the controller, not your class. Return the CSV data from the class and send it to the user in the controller.

Comment: @JohnP, it is automatically defining the disposition with those values. The response header contains `Content-Disposition attachment; filename="exported_properties.csv"; filename*=UTF-8''exported_properties.csv`.
`send_data` is at the controller.

Comment: So the `export_to_csv` method is in the controller? The [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) are probably the best place to look for info on how this works. There's even some sample code for a CSV file there. More generally, though, if the response is reaching the browser but not being shown, it's probably an issue with the headers - Rails isn't passing the info the browser needs to know what to do with the data, so you need to make sure you provide it by calling `send_data` correctly. Can't help more myself, though, I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `local: true` to the `from_with` method in the view solves the problem.

```rb
<%= form_with url: export_to_csv_admin_properties_url, local: true do |form| %>
```